# Does anyone have a good example / tutorial on how to use jQuery Form Upload?

Tags: jquery, file-upload

After testing [AjaxFileUpload Plugin](http://www.phpletter.com/Demo/AjaxFileUpload-Demo/) I discovered that it does not let me retrieve `$_POST` data, as the plugin only submits `$_FILE` data. Therefore I turn to jQuery Form Plugin which is documented here: http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/#file-upload

Unfortunately, I feel the example is poor and doesn't really help me. I need to use IFrame in order to prevent the page to reload.

Does anyone have some working code og link to god tutorials using jQuery Form plugin for uploading files using IFrame?

I know there are other file upload plugins, but I would like to use this one for this project.

**UPDATE**
This is the code I currently use. All it does is relaod the page and I get no output / alerts.

HTML

```
<form id="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" action=""  method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1000000" />
    <input type="hidden" id="current_path" name="current_path" value="<?php echo $fb->relative_url; ?>" />
    <input id="uploadFile" name="uploadFile" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" class="button uploadImage" value="<?php _e('Upload File') ?>" /> <br /> 
</form>
```

Javascript

```
var options = {
    beforeSubmit:   function() { alert('before');},
    success:        function(html) { alert('success + ' + html);},
    data:           {current_path: jQuery('#currentPath span').html()},
    url:            '../wp-content/plugins/wp-filebrowser/uploader.php',
    iframe:         true,
    dataType:       'html'
};

jQuery('#uploadForm').submit(function() {
    jQuery(this).ajaxSubmit(options);
    return false;
});
```

I also tried this JS

```
jQuery('#uploadForm').ajaxForm({
    beforeSubmit:   function() { alert('before');},
    success:        function(html) { alert('success + ' + html);},
    data:           {current_path: jQuery('#currentPath span').html()},
    url:            '../wp-content/plugins/wp-filebrowser/uploader.php',
    dataType:       'html'
});
```

But still my page only reloads and no alerts are fired :(

**DEBUG**

Running the following script in my JS file: `alert(jQuery('#uploadForm').ajaxForm);` gave me this output:

```
function (options) {
    if (this.length === 0) {
        var o = {s: this.selector, c: this.context};
        if (!jQuery.isReady && o.s) {
            log("DOM not ready, queuing ajaxForm");
            jQuery(function () {jQuery(o.s, o.c).ajaxForm(options);});
            return this;
        }
        log("terminating; zero elements found by selector" + (jQuery.isReady ? "" : " (DOM not ready)"));
        return this;
    }
    return this.ajaxFormUnbind().bind("submit.form-plugin", function (e) {if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {e.preventDefault();
jQuery(this).ajaxSubmit(options);}}).bind("click.form-plugin", function (e) {var target = e.target;
var jQueryel = jQuery(target);
if (!jQueryel.is(":submit,input:image")) {var t = jQueryel.closest(":submit");
if (t.length == 0) {return;}target = t[0];}var form = this;
form.clk = target;
if (target.type == "image") {if (e.offsetX != undefined) {form.clk_x = e.offsetX;
form.clk_y = e.offsetY;} else if (typeof jQuery.fn.offset == "function") {var offset = jQueryel.offset();
form.clk_x = e.pageX - offset.left;
form.clk_y = e.pageY - offset.top;} else {form.clk_x = e.pageX - target.offsetLeft;form.clk_y = e.pageY - target.offsetTop;}}setTimeout(function () {form.clk = form.clk_x = form.clk_y = null;}, 100);});
}
```

From the debugging, it looks like the form is not finished loading when I run this script. That's weird, because I have it inside `jQuery(document).ready()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/).

To get this code working, I use the following script:

```
  /*  Brand logo uploadify
  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/    
  function uploadifyBrandLogo()
  {

          //Get brand ID because loading uploadify.php triggers a new session
          var brand_id = jQuery('#brand_id').val();

          jQuery("#brand_btnBrowseLogo").uploadify({
            'uploader'       : siteURL + '/wp-content/plugins/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
            'script'         : siteURL + '/wp-content/plugins/uploadify/uploadify.php',
            'fileExt'        : '*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png',
            'auto'           : true,
            'multi'          : false,
            'method'         : 'POST',
            'height'         : '29',
            'width'          : '136',
            'buttonImg'      : siteURL + '/wp-content/themes/storelocator/img/buttons/img_upload_grey_bg.png',
            'cancelImg'      : siteURL + '/wp-content/plugins/uploadify/cancel.png', 
            'scriptData'     : {'var1':'data1','var2':data2},
            'onComplete'     : function(event, queueID, fileObj, response, data) { 
               // Do stuff here
               }

              // Show upload feedback
              showFeedback(result.feedback);                    
            }
          });
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

need to bind the submit event

```
 // bind form using 'ajaxForm' 
   // bind to the form's submit event 
    $('#myForm1').submit(function() { 
        // inside event callbacks 'this' is the DOM element so we first 
        // wrap it in a jQuery object and then invoke ajaxSubmit 
        $(this).ajaxSubmit(options); 

        // !!! Important !!! 
        // always return false to prevent standard browser submit and page navigation 
        return false; 
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you could be more specific about what you need to do. I've used the plug-in before though so can show a simple example.

You don't need an IFrame to prevent a page reload. I agree the documentation is pretty poor, I didn't really understand the IFrame bit but found it worked fine for me without one.

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("UploadDocument", "Documents", 
               new { wo = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["id"] },
               FormMethod.Post, 
               new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @class="attachDocumentsForm" }))
        {%>
            <input type="file" name="fileInput" class="attachDocumentFileInput" size="100"/>
            <input type="submit" class="attachDocumentsSubmit" value="Upload file" />       
            <input type="button" class="attachDocumentsCancel" value="Cancel" />       
        <% } %>    


$documentsForm.ajaxForm({
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSubmit: function() {
            // ...
        },
        success: function(data) {
            if (data) {
                // ...
            }
            else {
                alert('Error uploading document. Upload failed.');
            }
        }
    });
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. I tried your solution, but I still get the same result :( I've added the code I have tested. Do you see anything wrong with it?

Comment: @Steven: I've tested your code as in your 2nd example and it works perfectly for me. I think there is something else you are doing wrong. Are you sure you haven't got a mistake in the script reference to the jQuery.form file or something? Try `alert(jQuery('#uploadForm').ajaxForm);` on page load and check the function is defined.

Comment: Thanks for testing. Good to know that it's working somewhere. I've added the output of the `alert`. Looks like tehre are som problems... it says that `DOM is not ready` and `zero elements found by selector`. Not sure what I make out of that :(

Comment: I think you're just seeing the function definition, unless it's actually logging those errors somewhere. I'm out of ideas to be honest, not sure why it wouldn't be working for you. Only thing I could think is if maybe you had some invalid html somewhere that might affect it. Otherwise try having a play in firebug or chrome developer tools, might give you some clues. It's a strange one though.

Answer (score 0):

Uploadify is definitely the way to go; have a look at this for a bit more advice:

http://markp3rry.wordpress.com/2011/12/21/back-to-basics-file-uploads-view-jquery-net/